# Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I'm trying to calculate the Fourier transform of
$$
F(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{|\vec{r}|^2 - 1},
$$

where $\vec{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, in the sense of tempered distributions. I want to get it to find the inhomogeneous wave equation fundamental solution with Fourier analysis. I think it is related to the principal value distribution, but I have not managed to solve it until now...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on how you define the distribution $F$. Let $r, \rho \in \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathcal F[\phi](\rho) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} \phi(r) e^{i \rho \cdot r} dr$ for a test function $\phi$. If
$$(F, \phi) = \operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_0^\infty
 \frac {\phi_S(x)} {x^2 - 1} dx,$$
where $\phi_S(x) = \int_{|r| = x} \phi(r) dS$, then, similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3837439),
$$\mathcal F[F](\rho) = \frac {2 \pi^2 \cos |\rho|} {|\rho|}.$$

Comment: @Maxim I don't know how to define it either... I got F applying Fourier transform respect to position and time to the inhomogeneous wave equation with a Dirac delta source. I was trying to invert firstly the space coordinates, and that's how I got the previous expression. Maybe as you pointed out in the link it could be enough.

Comment: @Maxim And also, the expression you propose is coherent with the one given in some Electrodynamics books when solving similar problems using different approaches

Comment: Solving $(\Delta+1)G=\delta,$ where $G$ is spherically symmetric, using $\Delta=\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ gives
$$G(r)=Ay_0(r) + Bj_0(r),$$
where $j_0,y_0$ are [spherical Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn,_yn) and $A,B$ are constants. So the Fourier transform you are looking for should be of that form.

Comment: Use spherical co-ordinates for the Fourier integrals. The angular integrals are simple, and you are left with $\int\limits_0^\infty dr \ r \frac{e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}}{r^2-1}$, which can be written $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dr \ r \frac{e^{ikr}}{r^2-1}$. Then use contour integration, avoiding the poles on the real axis with little arcs.

Comment: See also the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233687).